# JAVA datagram packet length or offset error

Tags: java, networking, udp

I'm trying to create a server that reads the contents of a file and sends them to the client using datagram packets. Here's what I have so far:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("File.txt"));

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("File.txt"));
  
    DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket();

    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        DatagramPacket multi = new DatagramPacket(br.readLine().getBytes(), br.readLine().getBytes().length, InetAddress.getByName("224.0.0.5"), 7777);
        ds.send(multi);
        sc.nextLine();
        sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get an error that says

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal length or offset

The constructor I'm  using is

> DatagramPacket(byte[] buf, int length, InetAddress address, int port)
>
> Constructs a datagram packet for sending packets of length length to the specified port number on the specified host.

I do not understand why I am getting an error since I am passing the length as the second parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450619/unable-to-set-the-offset-for-buffer-in-the-datagrampacket-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code makes no sense whatsoever. You're setting the data of the `DatagramPacket` to the bytes of the next line, without checking for EOS, and you're setting its length to the length of the *following* line, and again without checking for EOS. So you can end up setting the length to less, or more, than the length of the data, neither of which makes sense, and you can encounter a `NullPointerException` at either step, which also makes no sense.

`readLine()` cannot possibly deliver the same thing twice in a row.

It also makes no sense whatsoever to use both a `Scanner` and a `BuferedReader` on the the same file, and to expect I/O done via one to affect the other.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to re-create a packet for each line of your text file.
Try this code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        // Creaete a reader
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("File.txt"));

        //Create a socket
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();

        // Create a packet
        byte[] data = new byte[1024]; // Max length
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);

        // Set the destination host and port 
        packet.setAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
        packet.setPort(9999);

        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            //Set the data
            packet.setData(line.getBytes());
            //Send the packet using the socket
            socket.send(packet);
            Thread.sleep(200);
        }

        //Close socket and file
        reader.close();
        socket.close();

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```