# illegal length or offset while passing double value from server to client by udp

Tags: java

I have the following situation: there's a client, which passes some values to server, server do some computation with this values and then passes them back to client. And I have an error while passing data back from server to client. Here's the way how I do it:

In server:

```
private void sendBack() {
        String str = String.valueOf(sum1 - sum2);
        System.out.println(str);
        byte[] send = str.getBytes();
        try {
            datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(send, send.length, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 12346);
            socket.send(datagramPacket);
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

In client:

```
datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(bytes, 18); //18, because it's the length of value which I pass from server
socket.receive(datagramPacket);
resultTf.setText(new String(datagramPacket.getData()));
```

But in client I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal length or offset
    at java.base/java.net.DatagramPacket.setData(DatagramPacket.java:267)
    at java.base/java.net.DatagramPacket.<init>(DatagramPacket.java:84)
    at java.base/java.net.DatagramPacket.<init>(DatagramPacket.java:100)
    at com.mikhailovskii.lab2.ui.UdpClientWindow.onCalculateClick(UdpClientWindow.java:96)
    at com.mikhailovskii.lab2.ui.UdpClientWindow.lambda$new$0(UdpClientWindow.java:61)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

I think, that the problem is in this line: `datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(bytes, 18);`, but I don't understand what's the matter and how can I solve this problem. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to set the offset for buffer in the datagramPacket object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450619/unable-to-set-the-offset-for-buffer-in-the-datagrampacket-object)

Comment: @GeorgeZ. in this question solution is that `length` + `offset` parameters should be less or equal than `bytes.length`. But I pass byte array, which length is 18. So, my less parameter is under this condition, so it doesn't solve my problem, unfortunately